# C# ASP.NET MVC resource file's string is in a strange encoding format in HTML source

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding, html-encode

Let's see an example: there is a German word: `Fußgängerübergänge`

What I have:

- `web.config` file:

  ```
  ...
  <system.web>
      <globalization
          fileEncoding="utf-8"
          requestEncoding="utf-8"
          responseEncoding="utf-8"
          culture="auto"
          uiCulture="auto"
      />
  ...
  ```
- a resource file containing this word:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
      ...
      <data name="TestWord" xml:space="preserve">
          <value>Fußgängerübergänge</value>       
      </data>
      ...
  </root>
  ```
- an html page hardcoded the same word and using this resource to reference this word and also retrieving this word from DB:

  ```
  ...
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      ...
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>Fußgängerübergänge</div>
      <div>@Model.SameWordFromDbTable.TestWord</div>
      <div>@Resources.MyResource.TestWord</div>
      <div>@MvcHtmlString.Create(Resources.MyResource.TestWord)</div>
  </body>
  ...
  ```
- When I check them in the source code of the webpage they appear in two different ways:

  ```
  ...
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      ...
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>Fußgängerübergänge</div>
      <div>Fußgängerübergänge</div>
      <div>Fu&#223;g&#228;nger&#252;berg&#228;nge</div>
      <div>Fu&#223;g&#228;nger&#252;berg&#228;nge</div>
  </body>
  ...
  ```

**Question**: what did I do wrong, how can I fix this "encoding" issue? What should I do if a want the last 2 words appear in the source code as same as the first two?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to prevent your text from being HTML encoded, you can simply use Html.Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(Resources.MyResource.TestWord)
```

Is the encoding actually a problem, though?

Comment: Ah, OK. That implies that your TestWord is already HTML encoded when it's pulled out of your resources - I'll try a couple of things and edit the answer. In the meantime, you could decode it with the messy looking: Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Resources.MyResource.TestWord))

Comment: Still the same, whatever comes from db or hardcoded are "pure"-texts whatever comes from resource is weird...
Whoever checks the website, the "view" of it is ok, but the source code is half-normal-half-encoded...
it might not be annoying for the viewers, but since I've no idea what cause this issue it's annoying for me :)

Comment: Strange... just tested <div>@Html.Raw(MyResource.TestWord)</div> myself, and it worked fine for me. I'm still trying things...

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate your issue. I've created a resources file under App_GlobalResources, that looks identical to yours, added a test word with a value of "Fußgängerübergänge", and @Html.Raw(Resources.MyResource.TestWord) works as expected - the word isn't HTML encoded. There must be another setting or... something... in your project that is affecting it.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. No problem... there must be something in the background that I miss...

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me:

```
alert('@Html.Raw(Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("Contractcheckalert"))');
```

### before

[image: Before Fix]

### after

[image: After the Fix]